# How can I run multiple threads in a Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have spent all day on this and I cannot figure out how to use multithreading in rails, without causing the following error:

```
Uncaught exception: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Docket::System::ExecutableFactory
    /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
    /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
```

The code works without threads, but as soon as I introduce threads, that is when I get the "circular dependency" error.

Below is the code in question:

```
def run
  records.in_groups_of(4) do |records|
    workers = records.map do |record|
      Thread.new do
        begin
          options[:record] = record
          county = create_county options
          county.prepare
          if county.ready
            county.crawl
          end
        rescue ThreadError => e
          puts "THREAD ERROR: #{e}"
        end
      end
    end
    workers.map(&:join)
  end
end

...

  def crawl
    cmd = "#{executable_factory.path} #{crawler_path}"
    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
      stdout_is = stdout.read
      stderr_is = stderr.read
    end
  end
```

Docket::System::ExecutableFactory is one of my classes, but I have it properly nested. Directory structure:

```
\docket
    \system
        executable_factory.rb
```

And I have it properly namedspace:

```
module Docket
  module System
    class ExecutableFactory
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

So why does this error occur with threads and how can I fix it?